# Output all dates of a year

Tags: javascript

I would like to list all dates and hour of a year with format mmddhh

Q1: Why I got "undefined" before the output? How can I fix it?

```js
var m, d, h, month, day, hour, output;
for (m = 1; m <= 12; m++) {
    month = addZero(m).toString();
    for (d = 1; d <= 31; d++) {
        day = addZero(d).toString();
        for (h = 1; h <= 24; h++) {
            hour = addZero(h).toString();
            output += month + day + hour + "<br>";
        }
    }
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = output;

function addZero(z) {
    var z
    if (z < 10)
        return "0" + z;
    else
        return z;
}
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```

Q2: I tried looping `d` 31 times using `if (m = "01" || "03" || "05" || "07" || "08" || "10" || "12")` else looping 30 times. However it is fail, how can I do that?

```js
    var m, d, h, month, day, hour, output;
    for (m = 1; m <= 12; m++) {
        month = addZero(m).toString();
        if (m = "01" || "03" || "05" || "07" || "08" || "10" || "12") {
            for (d = 1; d <= 31; d++) {
                day = addZero(d).toString();
                for (h = 1; h <= 24; h++) {
                    hour = addZero(h).toString();
                    output += month + day + hour + "<br>";
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (d = 1; d <= 30; d++) {
                day = addZero(d).toString();
                for (h = 1; h <= 24; h++) {
                    hour = addZero(h).toString();
                    output += month + day + hour + "<br>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = output;


    function addZero(z) {
        var z
        if (z < 10)
            return "0" + z;
        else
            return z;
    }
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared a variable called `output`, but it is not initialized with a value, so its value is undefined.

Then when you say `output += month + day + hour + "<br>";` it is really `output = undefined + month + day + hour + "<br>";`, thus you are getting an `undefined` at the beginning of the `output`

```js
var m, d, h, month, day, hour, output = "";
for (m = 1; m <= 12; m++) {
  month = addZero(m).toString();
  for (d = 1; d <= 31; d++) {
    day = addZero(d).toString();
    for (h = 1; h <= 24; h++) {
      hour = addZero(h).toString();
      output += month + day + hour + "<br>";
    }
  }
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = output;

function addZero(z) {
  var z
  if (z < 10)
    return "0" + z;
  else
    return z;
}
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Thx for your answer for Q1
Could you please help me for solution of Q2?

Comment: @Ming `m == "01" || m == "03" || m == "05" || m == "07" || m == "08" || m == "10" || m == "12"`